# How does a copy of the data in one data structure to another work in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a class that looks like:

```
class A
{
  public:
       A();
       void MethodThatWillNotBeInOtherStructure();

       inline int getData() { return data; }
       inline void setData(int data_) { data = data_; }

  private:
       int data;
}
```

and a structure like:

```
struct B
{
  public:         
       inline int getData() { return data; }
       inline void setData(int data_) { data = data_; }

  private:
       int data;
}
```

How can I copy an instance of A to B without individually setting the fields? I know I can as I have seen code that would take a void* of say A and pass it to a function expecting B and it work. My big question also, is how does this work? I suppose it has something to do with memcpy, but I don't know how the memory layout for the structure and the class will be. For example, how do the functions that are in one but not the other not get in the way of the memcpy? Could someone explain this to me?

**Update**

Ok, let me explain. I am not saying I would ever do this in reusable code or that I would ever use it period. I still want to know how it works. Does a class have a different memory layout than a structure? How are the methods stored? Where is the data stored?

Thanks!

Comment: The functions don't modify the memory layout at all UNLESS you changed one to be virtual, in which case a pointer is placed at the start of the class.  Additionally, as with C, memory layout will depend upon the alignment used for each class.

Comment: Methods are stored as regular functions in .text segment; classes with virtual methods have hidden pointer to table with pointers to virtual functions(they placed in .text segment aswell). So, object of a class with no virtual methods will be stored as chunk of memory large enough to hold all data fields(not less, but maybe larger than, depends of compiler options). And if class have virtual member functions, each object will contain additional virtual pointer(1 or more? not sure) to virtual method tables. I can be wrong. Check this http://www.phpcompiler.org/articles/virtualinheritance.html

Comment: @all Please put that into an answer so I can vote on it and accept.

Comment: @all: C++ standard does not have any mention of `vptr` or `vtable` & that is an implementation detail of the compilers, the standard just defines the behaviors during the dynamic displatch, while it is true that most compilers implement dynamic dispatch using `vptr` and `vtable`, it is important to note that some compiler may not do so since it may have its own implementation mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying two **unrelated** structures in to each other through `void *` would work properly only if the two structures have the same memory layout. Otherwise the copying fails.

Note that the objects of structure `A` and `B` in your above code will have the same memory layout, since there member variables are identical.

Copying through `void *` works because one is just copying the actual memory occupied by one structure object in to memory occupied by another structure object.

It is basically a bad idea to copy two unrelated structures in this way.

Consider the situation where you have pointers members inside your structure, a `memcpy` would just cause a **shallow copy** of the pointer members, And if one of the object finishes its lifetime then eventually, the other object will be left with a dangling pointer member. That would eventually lead to an Undefined behavior(most likely a crash).

***How are the methods stored? Where is the data stored?***
A normal function(non virtual) will be stored somewhere in the code section of the program. This location is the same for all instances of the class/structure and hence it is not a part of the memory allocation of each object of the class/structure.

In case of a virtual member function, the size of an class/structure does get affected due to presence of virtual functions, each object of the class/structure then has a special pointer called `vptr` inside each `this`. Note that this is implementation detail of compilers and compilers may choose to implement it differently.

Comment: Right, but suppose the actual data was identical and the only difference is the methods. There has to be some similarity in the memory layout. I couldn't do some pointer arithmetic and a memcpy?

Comment: @Jonathan Henson: Consider that if your structures have different memory layout or size for that matter, then object of one structure cannot be reliably copied in to object of another structure unless some memory beyond the bounds allocated for the structure object is overwritten, This memory if allocated to some other construct will eventually corrupt the stack.

Comment: I've considered that as well as the cloning issues, I still want to know how it works in the special case I have mentioned.

Comment: @Jonathan Henson: I do not understand what special case you are reffering to, I already mentioned `memcpy` just copies chunks of memory from source to destination, it does not understand it is copying struct or any other types, Whether what it does is correct or not depends on source and destination having same size and layout. What is not clear in this?

Comment: Yeah, I understand all that, I suppose my problem is not understanding how the functions fit into the equation. Where are they stored if not in the memory layout of the class?

Comment: @Jonathan Henson: Updated the answer with answers to your queries.

Comment: Thanks! thats what I need, one last question though. What about inlines? Does the same apply?

Comment: @Jonathan Henson: A member function declared as inline functions will atleast never increase the size of the object of class/structure, so yes same applies. On a side note, You are asking too many questions coupled up in a single Question, You should ask each as an separate question. Comments are for discussion on the answer not additional questions & for answering those in comments, it does not do justice to answering them cleanly, as this section is just too small for ellaborated answering.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the memory layout is quite important when you're using unsafe mechanisms like memcpy to copy the structure. Once it's modified later, you entire logic may screwed up.

Objects of a class doesn't contain the functions. The memory of an object contains only the attributes and the required size for it. On the other hand, functions are executable peice of code which is common across the program and will not influence the structure's memory layout.

I'd suggest you to define operator=, constructors to appropriately casting one object to another.

The additional glitch on memcpy is that, the object may contain virtual pointer if the class has virtual functions. Additional pointer data may also be copied to the destination memory; which is not really good!

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the A to B using memcpy since they have the same member variables. The functions are not part the instances, so they don't matter.

I would recommend against this approach. If either A or B changes, then your copy will fail at run-time. You can make a a constructor of B which takes A, a conversion function, or something. Though it will require a little more code, it will allow for changes to the structures.

Comment: Ok, 1st where are the functions stored in memory compared to the data? 2nd, I have higher educational purposes in the question. Just because I can do it doesn't mean I will. Sometimes, though I am certain that the code will not change.

Comment: The virtual functions are stored in the virtual table. I don't know where that is found in memory, but objects from virtual classes will have pointers to their virtual tables. Try this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table#Example

Comment: What about functions that will not be dynamically bound?

Comment: Non-virtual methods are compiled as functions - at least in GCC. So somewhere there is a function getData(A a). When you link, it links it just like non-OOP functions. In the case of inline functions, there would be no function; the code occurs in the caller's block.

Comment: And the non-virtual methods will not appear anywhere in the memory block for the structure or class? I.e. my memcpy will never encounter memory containing methods?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably to implement constructor of struct B that takes a const reference to a struct A. Use that directly or use the assignment operator (which you probably will need to implement for non-trivial cases).

```
A a;
... (populate a)

B b(a); //If you want to set b to a at instantiation.

b = B(a); //If you want to overwrite an existing instance of struct B with a.
```

**EDIT:**
To respond to your edit, it is entirely compiler dependent. The fact that it works at all for a class is reliant on compiler details, since AFAIK it's not supported by the standard. The compiler devs could decide to mess with people by making it work for CLASS but not STRUCT (or vice versa).

That said, I've never seen any difference in any compiler I've used. I would expect them to map memory identically.

Comment: This method will load the data of a class into the structure without any modification?

Comment: You have to implement it. It will do whatever you write it to do.